# Convert varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I (unfortunately) have some dates that were saved into varchar columns. These columns contain dates in the following format:

> mmddyy

For example:

> 010110

I need to import these values into a table which is set to datetime and formats dates like this:

> 2010-09-17 00:00:00.000

How can I convert the string above into a datetime value below?

Comment: your example could be binary (010110).  Just kidding.

Comment: bobs haha. yeah, should have used a better example. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CAST function will do this, the problem is that it will assume you first 2 digits are year. This should for for you:

```
SELECT CAST((RIGHT('010110',2) + LEFT('010110',4)) AS DATETIME)
```

This is assuming that all dates are MMDDYY.

Comment: This works great on a literal, but when I attempt to use it on the varchar field I get the error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: Issue was that I had added a 0 to the beginning of all five digit dates (e.g. 11010 instead of 011010) but then did a rollback - so I was trying to run this against incorrect strings, once I added and committed the leading 0 it all worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@date, 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 4) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the string into YYMMDD format and you should be in good shape:

```
declare @x varchar(6)
set @x = '091710'

declare @d datetime

set @d = cast(RIGHT(@x,2) + LEFT(@x,4) as datetime)

select @d
```

Answer (score 2):

Use substring to grab the relevant parts into a 'yyyy-mm-dd' format, then `cast` it to datetime:

```
cast(
    '20' + substring(col1,5,2) + '-' +
    substring(col1,1,2) + '-' +
    substring(col1,3,2)
    as datetime)
```

Answer (score 2):

That the supported date conversion styles are described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). The bad news is that there is no style for `mmddyy`. So you'll have to do a custom formating. How that is done depends on how you import. Is it an SSIS ETL step? Is it a one time table copy?

You can custom convert the format you specify straight from T-SQL:

```
declare @x varchar(6) = '010110';

select dateadd(month, cast(substring(@x, 1,2) as int)-1,
    dateadd(day, cast(substring(@x,3,2) as int)-1,
    dateadd(year, cast(substring(@x,5,2) as int),'01-01-2000')));
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
DECLARE @OldTable table (col1 int, col2 char(1), col3 char(6))
DECLARE @NewTable table (col1 int, col2 char(1), col3 datetime)
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (1,'A','010110') --mmddyy = jan  1, 2010
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (1,'A','091710') --mmddyy = sep 17, 2010

INSERT INTO @NewTable
        (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT
        col1, col2, RIGHT(col3,2) + LEFT(col3,4) --<< cast to datetime not needed... 
        FROM @OldTable                           --<< because @NewTable.col3 is datetime
        ORDER BY Col1

SELECT * FROM @NewTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
col1        col2 col3
----------- ---- -----------------------
1           A    2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
1           A    2010-09-17 00:00:00.000

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for a `varchar` string 6 characters long

```
CAST((RIGHT('130513',2) + ltrim(rtrim(right(left('130513', 4), 2))) + LEFT('130513',2) ) AS DATETIME)
```

This will convert the string to *13th May 2013*